# DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay() not giving proper format

Tags: c#, datetime

I don't have any problems running the program but i keep getting wrong output in tableAdapter.

```
OleDbCommand cmd4 = new OleDbCommand("Insert Into loginReport Values(?,?,?,?,?,?)", conn);cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", textBox1.Text);
cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("Account Type", "admin");
cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time(LOG-IN)", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay); //this where i get wrong output
cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time(LOG-OUT)", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay); //this where i get wrong output
cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date()", DateTime.Now.Date);
cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("Remarks", "admin");
cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Output:
[image]

In the `Time(Log-in/Log-out)` column, I need to get only the time `hh:mm am/pm` format, but where does that date(`12/30/1899`) come from? I believe this is something to do with the formats, but i don't know what to do. My database is fine, i checked the data types and the format of date/time. I selected the medium time and my database looks fine.
[image]

Comment: Which database are you using? And what are the column types in the database?  If it's SQL Server, you should use `time` types if you want no associated date.

Comment: Also recognize that `DateTime.Now` gives the time according to the local time zone where it is executed - which may or may not be correct for your scenario.  It also cannot disambiguate during a DST fall-back transition.  You should either record UTC-based values, or use a `datetimeoffset` data type.  Read: [The case against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)

Comment: @MattJohnson I'm using ms-access. `Username` `Account Type` and `Remarks` are `short text`, while `Time` and `Date` is `Date/Time`. `Time` and `Date` columns are differ only in formats.

Comment: I Agree with @MattJohnson. But I also like to add that it is better practice to explicitly format the date/time you are trying to pass into the DB so the DB can accept it and parse it to the expected format as best as it can. For instance do a ToString() on the DateTime.Now and format with: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss but that's just me.

Comment: 1899/12/30 is 0 in terms of dates. As such you're getting exactly what you wanted, storing only a time value, the date part is 0. The problem here is that whatever you're using to display the values with sees the type as a Date and Time, and thus displays the date as well. If you want to store only time, you need to use a data type that only holds time, if that is available in Access. If not, you got the best thing possible, just fix the display format.

Comment: The correct way to fix this problem would've been to use a data type that only stores time. Access, however, does not have such a data type and thus Date/Time is the next best thing. However, in .NET and most tools this will be interpreted as a value having both a date and a time (which is correct). You stored only time, and thus the date portion is 0. Displaying a DateTime value with a date portion of 0 will display 1899/12/30 for the date. The problem is thus with the displaying of the values, not with storing them.

Comment: To be clear. This is not a problem with "Parsing" the values, nor is it a problem with storing the data, insofar as the lack of a proper Time data type is not a problem. The only problem here is with displaying the values, using a format that includes the date, and then the 0-date is displayed. To properly display a datetime value as only time, a format string has to be used.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas - It is absolutely *not* a best practice to format a `DateTime` as a string when passing it to a database.  The native type mappings use a binary format over the wire, not a string in any particular format.  Passing dates as strings to a DB is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @MattJohnson - thanks for the correction. I agree with you totally but at times (I guess depending on the DB Engine), you can have date formatting issues per culture so specifying it in say, yyyy-MM-dd, seems to "fix" the problem. yes, most likely my knowledge is grey in this area and needs to be improved upon

Comment: @Ahmedilyas - sending as the native `DateTime` type instead of formatting as a string eliminates the culture issue.

Answer (score 1):

In NET there is no simple TIME type, there is only a DateTime type, so when you load the adapter with data returned by the db, NET could only store the value in a DateTime variable (or better in a DataColumn with DateTime type). Then when you display that data using a DataGridView the Date part of the column will be shown with the result that you can see.

To fix the "format" displayed by your grid you just need to supply your grid with the appropriate format specifier for your columns that show a DateTime value.

For example, assuming your grid is called `dgv` (after setting the DataSource)

```
dgv.Columns["Time(LOG-IN)"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss tt";
dgv.Columns["Time(LOG-OUT)"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss tt";
```

As a side note, I strongly suggest to avoid `AddWithValue` at all costs. This shorcut has many problems in particular when dealing with dates

[Can we stop to use AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Could the downvoter explain its reasons? The problem as the OP already knows is not in the database but in the way he chooses to use the default formatting in the datagridview used to display the value for the columns returned by the Adapter

Comment: As Lasse said, i need to fix the display format, so i'm hoping this would fix my problem. I did try to put this code in the method form loads but i'm getting error with, NullReferenceException was unhandled, could you identify where should i put that code?i'm willing to post the source code

Comment: After setting the DataSource of your DataGridView

Answer (score -1):

Your code is automatically being parsed into SQL and as a result your database is inserting the default datetime value which is 12/30/1899. You must declare a date time variable in C# first, set it, and then pass in the variable i.e.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;    
OleDbCommand cmd4 = new OleDbCommand("Insert Into loginReport Values(?,?,?,?,?,?)", conn);cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", textBox1.Text);
                cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("Account Type", "admin");
                cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time(LOG-IN)", now); //this where i get wrong output
                cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time(LOG-OUT)", now); //this where i get wrong output
                cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date()", now);
                cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("Remarks", "admin");
                cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
```

Comment: This will change nothing except that you will store the full date and time of "now", not just the time of day. Nothing is being "parsed" here, he's sending a DateTime value to the database, your code does the exact same thing. The value is different but the OP said he only needed the time, as such the *value* he is sending to the database is correct but since the data type is incorrect in that it also contains a date portion, displaying the data will try to interpret the time value without a date as having a date, and the date equivalent of "0" is 1899/12/30 in this case.

Comment: @Lasse Thank you for the clarification. You are correct in that I did not catch that he was only looking for the time. I read through the question too quickly. Thanks again!